# Big O notation when n multiplied by 4 every iteration

Tags: algorithm

what is the big o notation  of the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i=*4) 
{
    print('something ');
}
```

as far as i know it should be O(log n) but i heard someone says that n should be multiplied or divided by only 2 not any number else to be log n
is that correct?

Comment: This loop won't run, since the loop condition (`i > 7`) is false when the loop starts up. Did you mean something like `i < n`?

Comment: yeah, I just noticed that but anyway this was not my point, but i edited the code though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, and what you heard is wrong.

When the counter follows a geometric progression up to a limit, the number of iterations is logarithmic with respect to that limit.

Changing the multiplier just changes the base of the logarithm involved, but from a big-O perspective, the base of the logarithm is irrelevant. As long as it's a logarithm in some base, the complexity is O(log N).